# Convert MP4, AVI, MOV file to a collection of PNG, JPG or GIF frames

Tags: images

Is there any FREE software that I can use to convert a MP4, AVI or MOV file to a collection of images that are GIF, JPG or PNG?

Comment: Related: [How do I convert a video to GIF using ffmpeg, with reasonable quality?](http://superuser.com/q/556029/87805) However this should be asked at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Avidemux](http://avidemux.org/) can save a selection as a sequence of JPEGs.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with `mplayer` esp if you prefer a command line tool. Check out the `-vo` option (e.g. `-vo png`, `-vo jpeg`, etc). Use option `-ss 01:10:00` to seek to the starting position in the video and `-endpos xx` to save xx seconds of video.

For example:

```
mplayer -vo png -ss 00:00:07 -endpos 3 '/home/mlissner/Pictures/2010, California Coast/110_0396.MOV'
```

Answer (score 0):

[VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) can save image sequences as BMP, TARGA or JPEG. To export a video segment as a sequence of numbered images on disk in VirtualDub, use `File > Save Image Sequence`.

Comment: VirtualDub cannot open MP4 files.