# How do I convert a video to GIF using ffmpeg, with reasonable quality?

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

I'm converting a video to GIF file with `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg \
  -i input.flv \
  -ss 00:00:00.000 \
  -pix_fmt rgb24 \
  -r 10 \
  -s 320x240 \
  -t 00:00:10.000 \
  output.gif
```

It works great, but output gif file has a very low quality.

Any ideas how can I improve quality of converted gif?

Comment: Excellent post from giphy engineers https://engineering.giphy.com/how-to-make-gifs-with-ffmpeg/

Comment: I had this same macroblocking issue with Clipchamp export to gif feature. I'm mentioning this for the algorithm.

Comment: If you don't want any scaling: ```ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -y -vf 'fps=50,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse' -loop 0 output.gif```. fps=50 is the maximum highly compatible value.

Answer (score 1014, accepted):

## `ffmpeg` example

[image: GIF output from ffmpeg]
<sub>183k</sub>

`ffmpeg` can output high quality GIF. Before you start it is always recommended to use a recent version: [download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide).

```
ffmpeg -ss 30 -t 3 -i input.mp4 \
    -vf "fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" \
    -loop 0 output.gif
```

- This example will skip the first 30 seconds (`-ss 30`) of the input and create a 3 second output (`-t 3`).
- [fps](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps) filter sets the frame rate. A rate of 10 frames per second is used in the example.
- [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filter will resize the output to 320 pixels wide and automatically determine the height while preserving the aspect ratio. The lanczos [scaling algorithm](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-scaler.html) is used in this example.
- [palettegen](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#palettegen) and [paletteuse](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#paletteuse) filters will generate and use a custom palette generated from your input. These filters have many options, so refer to the links for a list of all available options and values. Also see the **Advanced options** section below.
- [split](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split) filter will allow everything to be done in one command and avoids having to create a temporary PNG file of the palette.
- Control looping with `-loop` output option but the values are confusing. A value of `0` is infinite looping, `-1` is no looping, and `1` will loop once meaning it will play twice. So a value of 10 will cause the GIF to play 11 times.

### Advanced options

The [palettegen](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#palettegen) and [paletteuse](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#paletteuse) filters have many additional options. The most important are:

- `stats_mode` (palettegen). You can force the filters to focus the palette on the general picture (`full` which is the default), only the moving parts (`diff`), or each individual frame (`single`). For example, to generate a palette for each individual frame use `palettegen=stats_mode=single` & `paletteuse=new=1`.
- `dither` (paletteuse). Choose the dithering algorithm. There are three main types: deterministic (`bayer`), error diffusion (all the others including the default `sierra2_4a`), and none. Your GIF may look better using a particular dithering algorithm, or no dithering at all. If you want to try `bayer` be sure to test the `bayer_scale` option too.

See [High quality GIF with FFmpeg](http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html) for explanations, example images, and more detailed info for advanced usage.

Also see the [palettegen](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#palettegen) and [paletteuse](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#paletteuse) documentation for all available options and values.

---

## ImageMagick `convert` example

[image: GIF output from ffmpeg]
<sub>227k</sub>

Another command-line method is to pipe from `ffmpeg` to `convert` (or `magick`) from ImageMagick.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos" -c:v pam \
    -f image2pipe - | \
    convert -delay 10 - -loop 0 -layers optimize output.gif
```

`ffmpeg` options:

- `-vf "fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos"` a [filtergraph](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-description) using the [fps](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps) and [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filters. fps sets frame rate to 10, and scale sets the size to 320 pixels wide and height is automatically determined and uses a value that preserves the aspect ratio. The lanczos [scaling algorithm](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-scaler.html) is used in this example.
- `-c:v pam` Chooses the pam image encoder. The example outputs the PAM (Portable AnyMap) image format which is a simple, lossless RGB format that supports transparency (alpha) and is supported by `convert`. It is faster to encode than PNG.
- `-f image2pipe` chooses the image2pipe muxer because when outputting to a pipe `ffmpeg` needs to be told which muxer to use.

`convert` options:

- `-delay` See **Setting frame rate** section below.
- `-loop 0` makes infinite loop.
- `-layers optimize` Will enable the general purpose GIF optimizer. See [ImageMagick Animation Optimization](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_opt/) for more details. It is not guaranteed that it will produce a smaller output, so it is worth trying without `-layers optimize` and comparing results.

#### Setting frame rate

Set frame rate with a combination of the [fps](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps) filter in `ffmpeg` and [`-delay`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#delay) in `convert`. This can get complicated because `convert` just gets a raw stream of images so no fps is preserved. Secondly, the `-delay` value in `convert` is in *ticks* (there are 100 ticks per second), not in frames per second. For example, with `fps=12.5` = 100/12.5 = 8 = `-delay 8`.

`convert` rounds the `-delay` value to a whole number, so 8.4 results in 8 and 8.5 results in 9. This effectively means that **only some frame rates are supported** when setting a uniform delay over all frames (a specific delay can be set per frame but that is beyond this answer).

`-delay` appears to be ignored if used as an output option, so it has to be used before `-` as shown in the example.

Lastly, browsers and image viewers may implement a minimum delay, so your `-delay` may get ignored anyway.

<sub>Video courtesy of U.S. Fish & Wildlife Service National Conservation Training Center.</sub>

Comment: Added some example results (just still frames though). Here, the first file is 4.1 MB, the second around 8 MB.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, you are awesome! much thanks for `-vf scale=320:-1,format=rgb8,format=rgb24`

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - the `convert` option worked brilliantly - also using an ancient version of ffmpeg directly got a file size of 300Mb with rubbish output, whilst the high quality one from convert was 13Mb...

Comment: By the way, for the `convert` command for converting from the PNG frames I ended up using `convert -delay 5 -loop 0 -dither None -colors 80 "frames/ffout*.png" -fuzz "40%" -layers OptimizeFrame  "output.gif"`, which reduces the overall file size quite a bit

Comment: I think the `convert` command should be using `-delay 10` (0.1 seconds between frames) to match the `-r 10` (10 fps) frame rate you're feeding to `ffmpeg`. When I use `-delay 5`, I see the gif play at double speed.

Comment: Is it it possible to crop a few pixels from the resulting GIF? I love these funny GIF from real movies/cartoons scenes, but I've found one, with a bad quality, in which the top... 5cm, more or less, is damaged. If I need to open a new thread I'll gladly

Comment: Bravo! I used the "ffmpeg example" to convert a CamStudio recording of my screen showing a RAID5 parity recovery of a flash drive RAID5 array. The recovery took about an hour. During that time, I teed the output to a text file. The video was actually the recording of my parsing the text. the AVI was 1.4 GB; the GIF was 2.5 MB.

Comment: In the second approach, you can use ffmpeg instead of imagick. All you need to do, is to use the image2 demuxer's **framrate** option, so you can set the delay between individual frames: `ffmpeg -framerate -i frames/ffout*.png output.gif`

Comment: Your ffmpeg example has become a common enough workflow for me that I wrote a bash wrapper script to automate it. Sharing here: https://github.com/jordanh/ffmpeg2gif

Comment: How if i don't want to set the scale, i need to make him the the video's scale automatically?

Comment: Okay, I've got it, i used `scale=0:-1`, so when you set the scale to `0`, it will take the scale from the video.

Comment: Giphy Engineering has released a nice article recently explaining all the options: https://engineering.giphy.com/how-to-make-gifs-with-ffmpeg

Comment: @LordNeckbeard How to can I modify your code to take let's say from a particular interval of a movie of let's say between 00:24:45 to 00:25:52? I tried to use the seek command and it did not work!. Can you perhaps help me with this?. I would like to know how to make it work with the palette you say to make and use ffmpeg to build up from that the gif. Btw I used the code as you mention and it works but to take a sample from longer intervals such as I mentioned is not very practical as I have to translate the minutes or hours to seconds.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Also the framerate you use how did you obtained?. Does it come from the input movie or is it just a random value that you chosen?

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell I chose a value low enough to make the GIF smaller in file size, but high enough to look acceptable. You'll just have to experiment depending on your content.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thanks for replying back, but I'd appreciate you could help me with the part of the code regarding time as I'm not too saavy enough to do that modification by myself. As I mentioned I tried to use seek command as ffmpeg documentation suggests the way of    -ss 00:24:25 to 00:25:52

Comment: @LordNeckbeard just after the input but I can't make ffmpeg to interpret the command the way I need, perhaps can you help me with that?. I'd be really grateful.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell Might be worth asking this as a new question and I or someone else can help. Comments may be too limited.

Comment: Trying the very first command - to generate the pallette (with ffmpeg-4.0.1): `Option 'flags' not found`. ffmpeg would've been _a lot_ more useful, if the developers knew the concept of backwards compatibility...

Comment: @MikhailT. Works for me. Please show your actual command and the complete log. You can use a pastebin site and provide the link here.

Comment: Err, never mind. I tried removing the `scale=360` part and that didn't work. Don't know, why...

Comment: @MikhailT. The full scale part is `scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos`. The `flags` is an option for scale. I probably should not have included that in the example as it increased complexity of the example.

Comment: This Q&A must be permanently encoded in a tome (or maybe just "pinned" for now) because in a hundred years from now all communication will be done via memes.  I think the activity on this post alone speaks to that.

Comment: What is [x]  ?? Why nobody on the whole earh mentioned this [x]?

Comment: @user1308990 `[x]` is just the label of the output coming from the `fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos` filterchain. The label is then referred to by other, separate filterchains or the output file. The label can be almost any arbitrary name, so you could rename it to whatever makes most sense to you. See [FFmpeg Filtering: Introduction](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) for more info.

Comment: For the ffmpeg-only solution, I encourage the use of [this brilliant single call with filter graph solution](https://superuser.com/a/1256459/535934) from @alijandro

Comment: Please describe all options, what is `-c:v pam`?

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich Answer updated.

Comment: I tried creating a GIF of 3 seconds from a 990 KB video of resolution 640 * 360 having a duration of 14 seconds. But the output GIF is having a size of 1.17 MB. I'm using `ffmpeg` command. `ffmpeg -t 3 -i inputfile.mp4 -vf ""fps = 10,scale = 320:-1:flags = lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0] palettegen[p];[s1] [p] paletteuse"" -loop 0 outputfile.gif`. Is there any way to reduce the size without using `ImageMagick`?

Comment: @Farshan GIF is an antiquated format, so size will always be relatively high. Use a lower fps, smaller scale, and/or shorter `-t`. You can also reduce the number of colors as in `palettegen=max_colors=64`.

Comment: Wow; thank you. My animated gifs are now incredibly improved.

Comment: [Source for why `lanczos` is a good choice here](https://superuser.com/a/375726/147688). TLDR good for both downsampling and upsampling.

Comment: @llogan My bad, VLC was the culprit. I didn't know it couldn't read gifs. I'll delete the comments

Comment: @llogan I found your snippet in a code base recently when trouble shooting why ffmpeg used so much memory, and takes so much time. Turns out that by slicing out the duration beforehand to a temporary file with the same container as input (null audio video copy), and then doing the fps/scale/palette/gif uses a fraction of the memory in a fraction of the time. No idea why, one guess is that palette operates on the whole video otherwise, not sure.

Comment: @dsvensson Never noticed a memory issue (but I'm not making GIFs often and they are using inputs only seconds long). How can the issue be duplicated? What are your commands to resolve it? You can use a pastebin link. Thanks.

Comment: It is giving No such filter: 'palettegen'
Error opening filters! 

error

Comment: @mayank1513 Your ffmpeg must be really old, or you have configured it to remove support for this filter.

Comment: I don't know if you have ever faced the problem which i faced but let me explain you, in some devices when you pick `Camera Video` to convert to `Gif` it will gets stretched because if video is portrait, means orientation is `0` but still it will show `90` or `270`, this will only happens to `Camera Videos`, not to other videos and not on every device(currently in `Samsung, OnePlus` works fine but not on `Realme`).

Comment: @VivekThummar Should be asked as a new question.

Comment: @llogan if you measure ffmpeg memory usage on some long 4k hq video with your command line parameters, and then compared that to if you just slice the first second - and in a second invocation perform the gif conversion you should notice reduced memory usage. /usr/bin/time -v is your mem stats friend.

Comment: You're a legend.

Comment: This doesn't work with `ffmpeg` 6.0. I get an error about `lanczos` deprecated or not found.

Answer (score 105):

If you would prefer to avoid intermediate image files, the commands provided by LordNeckBeard can be piped between `ffmpeg` and ImageMagick's `convert` so that no intermediate files are required:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -vf scale=320:-1 -r 10 -f image2pipe -vcodec ppm - | convert -delay 10 -loop 0 - output.gif
```

The `-f image2pipe` tells ffmpeg to split the video into images and make it suitable to be piped out, and `-vcodec ppm` specifies the output format to be ppm (for some reason if the format is png, either `convert` does not read all the images from the pipe, or ffmpeg does not output them all). The `-` for both commands specifies that a pipe will be used for output and input respectively.

To optimize the result without saving a file, you can pipe the output from `convert` to a second `convert` command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -vf scale=320:-1 -r 10 -f image2pipe -vcodec ppm - | convert -delay 10 -loop 0 - gif:- | convert -layers Optimize - output.gif
```

The `gif:-` tells `convert` to pipe its output as gif formatted data and `-layers Optimize` tells the second `convert` to perform `optimize-frame` and `optimize-transparancy` methods (see the ImageMagick [Introduction to Animation Optimization](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_opt/)). Note that the output from the `-layers Optimize` may not always provide a smaller file size, so you may want to try converting to a gif without optimization first to be sure.

Remember that during this whole process everything is in memory so you may need sufficient memory if the images are quite large.

Comment: This set of commands also works with `avconv`

Comment: You should merge the last two convert commands: `convert -delay 5 -loop 0 -layers Optimize - output.gif`

Comment: The gif appears to be running at 2x the speed of the source video?

Comment: @Titan believe it's the -r 10 in the first command and the -delay 5 in the second. I changed the delay to 10 also and it seems to play normally now.

Comment: You can also avoid intermediate image files by using the `split` filter in ffmpeg. No need to pipe anything at all: `ffmpeg -ss 30 -t 3 -i "input.flv fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,split[x][z];[z]palettegen[y];[x][y]paletteuse" output.gif`

Comment: Is there a way to maintain the scale? For example, my video file is 904:774. How do I do it without setting `scale=320:-1`? Is there a way to automate it without exploding the size?

Comment: @Ajedi32 Thanks. You forgot the `-vf` though, it should be `ffmpeg -ss 30 -t 3 -i input.flv -vf "fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,split[x][z];[z]palettegen[y];[x][y]paletteuse" output.gif`

Answer (score 53):

As of ffmpeg 2.6, we can do even better. Based on [High quality GIF with FFmpeg](http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html#usage):

```bsh
palette="/tmp/palette.png"
filters="fps=15,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos"

ffmpeg -i input.flv -vf "$filters,palettegen" -y $palette
ffmpeg -i input.flv -i $palette -lavfi "$filters [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse" -y output.gif
```

Comment: what does this do?

Comment: I tried and get an error:  The specified filename 'palette.png' does not contain an image sequence pattern or a pattern is invalid.

Answer (score 32):

The answer from @Stephane is very good. But it will get a warning like `Buffer queue overflow, dropping.` for some video, and the generated `gif` has some frame dropped.

Here is a better version with `fifo` filter to avoid `Buffer queue overflow` when using `paletteuse` filter. By using `split` filter to avoid the creation of intermediate palette PNG file.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex 'fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,split [o1] [o2];[o1] palettegen [p]; [o2] fifo [o3];[o3] [p] paletteuse' out.gif
```

Comment: If I understand that correctly, you are splitting the input into o1 and o2, and copying o2 to o3. So why do you need o3? Why not just use o2 directly?

Comment: @Chloe Did you see the `fifo` filter operation between `o2` and `o3`? To avoid the `Buffer queue overflow` warning.

Answer (score 29):

I made my own version of [this script](http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html#usage), which parameterizes the output resolution and frame rate as well.

Running `./gifenc.sh input.mov output.gif 720 10` will output 720p wide 10fps GIF from the movie you gave it. You might need to do `chmod +x gifenc.sh` for the file.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

palette="/tmp/palette.png"

filters="fps=$4,scale=$3:-1:flags=lanczos"

ffmpeg -v warning -i "$1" -vf "$filters,palettegen" -y "$palette"
ffmpeg -v warning -i "$1" -i $palette -lavfi "$filters [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse" -y "$2"
```

You can read the details on my [Github](https://github.com/thevangelist/FFMPEG-gif-script-for-bash)

Assumptions: ffmpeg is installed,
and the script is in the same folder as the other files.

Comment: Thank you so much for your script. I just tested it and it works great!

Comment: This script is exactly what I wanted - a super easy way to convert OBS screen captures to gifs for bug reporting

Answer (score 20):

#### Linux/Unix/macOS

Following [@LordNeckbeard approach](https://superuser.com/a/556031/87805) with `ffmpeg` command, please find the following useful Bash function which can be added into your `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
# Convert video to gif file.
# Usage: video2gif video_file (scale) (fps)
video2gif() {
  ffmpeg -y -i "${1}" -vf fps=${3:-10},scale=${2:-320}:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen "${1}.png"
  ffmpeg -i "${1}" -i "${1}.png" -filter_complex "fps=${3:-10},scale=${2:-320}:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" "${1}".gif
  rm "${1}.png"
}
```

Once the function is loaded (manually or from `. ~/.bash_profile`), you should have new `video2gif` command.

Example usage:

```
video2gif input.flv
```

or:

```
video2gif input.flv 320 10
```

<sup>Scale to 320 width with 10 frames per second.</sup>

You can also specify a different video format (such as mp4).

---

#### macOS

You can try [GIF Brewery](https://gfycat.com/gifbrewery) app which can create GIFs from video files.

---

Alternatively there are several websites which are doing conversion online free of charge.

Comment: your script raises an error for me about no png file and I get no gif output, but the .mp4 input file remains unchanged

Comment: Thanks. Params of ```1500``` and ```40``` for me personally generate perfect quality gifs.

Answer (score 17):

The selected answer assumes you wish to scale the source video and change its fps in the gif produced. If you do not need to do this, the following works:

```
src="input.flv"
dest="output.gif"
palette="/tmp/palette.png"

ffmpeg -i $src -vf palettegen -y $palette
ffmpeg -i $src -i $palette -lavfi paletteuse -y $dest
```

This came in handy when I wanted a gif that faithfully recreated the source video I was using.

Answer (score 15):

The `ffmpeg` with palette [method](https://superuser.com/a/556031/4368) can be run in a single command, without intermediary `.png` file.

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 30 -t 3 -i input.flv -filter_complex \
"fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x]split[x1][x2]; \
[x1]palettegen[p];[x2][p]paletteuse" output.gif
```

This can be done thanks to the [`split`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split_002c-asplit) filter.

Answer (score 11):

made a script, tested and works.

usage:

```
./avi2gif.sh ./vokoscreen-2015-05-28_12-41-56.avi
```

HAVE PHUN :)

vim avi2gif.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

INPUT=$1

# default settings, modify if you want.

START_AT_SECOND=0; # in seconds, if you want to skip the first 30 seconds put 30 here

LENGTH_OF_GIF_VIDEO=9999999; # in seconds, how long the gif animation should be

echo "Generate a palette:"
ffmpeg -y -ss $START_AT_SECOND -t $LENGTH_OF_GIF_VIDEO -i $INPUT -vf fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen palette.png

echo "Output the GIF using the palette:"
ffmpeg -ss $START_AT_SECOND -t $LENGTH_OF_GIF_VIDEO -i $INPUT -i palette.png -filter_complex "fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" $INPUT.gif
```

btw: [vokoscreen](http://www.kohaupt-online.de/hp/) is an EXCELLENT ScreenCapturing tool for Linux :)

THANKS A LOT Michael Kohaupt :) Rock steady.

some file size stats:

5.3M = vokoscreen-2015-04-28_15-43-17.avi
->
vokoscreen-2015-05-28_12-41-56.avi.gif = 1013K

see the [results here.](http://dwaves.de/2015/05/28/gimp-how-to-move-a-text-field-around/)

Answer (score 9):

For Windows users: create a file `\Windows\video2gif.bat` with this content:

```bat
@echo off
set arg1=%1
set arg2=%arg1:~0,-4%
ffmpeg -y -i %arg1% -vf fps=10,scale=-1:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen %TEMP%\palette.png
ffmpeg -i %arg1% -i %TEMP%\palette.png -filter_complex "fps=10,scale=-1:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" %arg2%.gif
del /f %TEMP%\palette.png
```

And then you can use it anywhere like this:

```
video2gif myvideo.mp4
```

Then you have `myvideo.gif` next to your original input file. If `myvideo.gif` already exists, you will be asked to overwrite it.

I suggest using [this versatile batch script](https://github.com/NabiKAZ/video2gif/blob/master/video2gif.bat).

Comment: I see that you have done two things here: (1) written the commands as a Windows (.BAT) command script, and  (2) provided a different combination of filters (none of the other answers uses *both* `fps=10` and `scale=-1:-1`).  [Sun’s answer](//superuser.com/q/556029/150988#1092909) already gave us a batch file, and that one (like the shell scripts in [pje’s answer](//superuser.com/q/556029/150988#893031) and [thevangelist’s answer](//superuser.com/q/556029/150988#939527)) has the advantage that it assigns the list of filters to a variable (*once*),  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  so it doesn’t need to spell out the list twice (as your batch file does).   (I presume that this creates a risk that, if the user edits the script to change one of the lists but not the other, the inconsistency will cause a problem.)   Can you at least explain your choice of filters (`fps=10,scale=-1:-1`)?   (See [notedible’s answer](//superuser.com/q/556029/150988#730389) for an example of an explanation of parts of a command.)

Comment: @Scott You said correct, so I write a new useful script in here: https://github.com/NabiKAZ/video2gif

Comment: https://github.com/NabiKAZ/video2gif works great even in 2022!

Answer (score 7):

#### ffmpeg commands:

1. Run this command so that ffmpeg can figure out a good palette:

   ```
   ffmpeg -y -i foo.mp4 -vf fps=30,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen palette.png
   ```
2. Run this command to convert the mp4 file into gif:

   ```
   ffmpeg -y -i foo.mp4 -i palette.png -filter_complex "fps=30,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" foo.gif
   ```

You might want to tweak the fps and scale. Smaller for either will result in better file size.

#### Making a simple alias function

You can also create an alias function like this. I added it to my `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

```
function makegif {
  ffmpeg -y -i $1 -vf fps=30,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen palette.png
  ffmpeg -y -i $1 -i palette.png -filter_complex "fps=30,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" $1.gif
}
```

And then just `makegif foo`

Note: You'll need ffmpeg of course. Get it here https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html or `brew install ffmpeg`

Comment: Thank you for the alias function. It is very handy

Comment: The FFmpeg portion of this answer is nearly identical to that in [llogan's answer](https://superuser.com/a/556031/34985) except this one creates an intermediate palette file and provides no descriptions or documentation links.  The alias portion of this answer (which answers a different question, anyways) is identical to [kenorb's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1154859/34985) except this one lacks the path quoting and `fps` and `scale` parameters.  -1 for not adding anything new.

Comment: how do i disable frame dropping and previous image ghosting? my complex filter is this `fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse`

Answer (score 5):

## How to add a windows 7/10 "right-click" context menu entry to convert your video file to gif

Some of the other answers mentioned the [video2gif](https://github.com/NabiKAZ/video2gif) script, which I used. But, you could use any script.

To create the context-menu option, you need to edit your registry. Open a powershell command prompt, running w/ admin privs. Execute these commands:

```
$key = "Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\`*\shell\Run Video2Gif"
New-Item -Path $key"\Command" -Value "C:\dev\ffmpeg\ffmpeg-3.4.2-win64-static\bin\video2gif.bat `"%1`"" -Force
```

Now when you right click a file you'll have a "Run Video2Gif" option!

btw I installed ffmpeg to `C:\dev\ffmpeg\ffmpeg-3.4.2-win64-static\` and put the `video2gif.bat` script in the bin dir right next to `ffmpeg.exe`. I also added `C:\dev\ffmpeg\ffmpeg-3.4.2-win64-static\bin` to my windows `PATH`, but I don't think you need to.

If you want the option of being able to supply some extra command line flags / args to the script, then make a new file named `video2gif-prompt.bat`, and have the registry referce it instead of `video2gif.bat`:

```
@echo off
set /p inp=Enter extrta args, if desired:
C:\dev\ffmpeg\ffmpeg-3.4.2-win64-static\bin\video2gif.bat %* %inp%
```

You can still just hit enter to quickly get the defaults.

Answer (score 4):

Below is the batch file for Windows users:

**gifenc.bat:**

```
set start_time=0
set duration=60
set palette="c:\temp\palette.png"
set filters="fps=15,scale=-1:-1:flags=lanczos"
ffmpeg -v warning -ss %start_time% -t %duration% -i %1 -vf "%filters%,palettegen" -y %palette%
ffmpeg -v warning -ss %start_time% -t %duration% -i %1 -i %palette% -lavfi "%filters% [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse" -y %2
```

Source: [High quality GIF with FFmpeg: Extracting just a sample](http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html)

If you just want to use one input variable and have the output name have just the GIF (pronounced JIF) extension, then use this instead:

```
set start_time=0
set duration=60
set palette="c:\temp\palette.png"
set filters="fps=15,scale=-1:-1:flags=lanczos"
ffmpeg -v warning -ss %start_time% -t %duration% -i %1 -vf "%filters%,palettegen" -y %palette%
set var1=%1
set var2=%var1:~0,-4%
ffmpeg -v warning -ss %start_time% -t %duration% -i %1 -i %palette% -lavfi "%filters% [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse" -y %var2%.gif
```

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick can do this simply:

```
convert in.mp4 out.gif
```

Comment: That doesnt answer the question though.  With 14 answers there already this needed to be spectacular.

Comment: @RohitGupta The `ffmpeg` example in [llogan's example](https://superuser.com/a/556031/261550) doesn't work with `ffmpeg` 6.0. I get an error about `lanczos` deprecated or not found.

Answer (score 1):

My simple trick to GIF conversion is the HandBrake/ffmpeg NLmeans filter. In HandBrake, just tick the NLMeans options in the video config tab.

It smooths out the rough GIF image, making it more easily compressable. The output looks nicer AND has a smaller size.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the steps on how one can use Handbrake/ffmpeg to do this?

Comment: For HB, just tick the NLMeans options in video config tab.

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.gif
```