# Clarification for ffmpeg input option with image files as input

Tags: ffmpeg

I have some images and I'd like to make an animated gif with ffmpeg.
The images have names as:

```
837_1.png
838_1.png
...
```

I'm trying to unserstand the **-i** command line option of ffmpeg but I am crashing against some problems.

If I don't specify anything it ask me to replace the files:

```
ffmpeg -i * -vcodec libx264 out.mp4

ffmpeg version 1.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 26 2013 20:18:03 with Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/1.2.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-vda --cc=cc --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, image2, from '358_1.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24, 550x550, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File '359_1.png' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N]
```

And if I try to use one of the most used format (%d) in the internet.. ffmpeg does not find the files:

```
fmpeg -i '%3d_1.png' -vcodec libx264 out.mp4

ffmpeg version 1.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 26 2013 20:18:03 with Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/1.2.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-vda --cc=cc --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[image2 @ 0x7f963a006600] Could find no file with with path '%3d_1.png' and index in the range 0-4
%3d_1.png: No such file or directory
```

So.. here is the question, how to use the **-i** command line option with ffmpg?

For sake of clarity, I am on Mac OSX 10.8, ffmpeg version 1.2.1, zsh 4.3.11

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Without any further options, ffmpeg's `image2` demuxer will look for a sequence starting with 0. It'll also check around this index, with a default range of 5 (that's why it'll complain about no index in the range 0–4). Per [the documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#image2-1), you have to set the start number if you want to start at an arbitrary index, like 837.

```
ffmpeg -start_number 837 -i '%3d_1.png' -c:v libx264 out.mp4
```

---

#### Color space in PNG to H.264 conversion

Since PNG files use the RGB color space to represent pixels, the conversion to H.264 would end up being YUV 4:4:4 ([non-subsampled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling)). The resulting video may not be playable on all players, notably anything non-FFmpeg-based. Your player would show only black frames, or possibly crash. To fix that, change the pixel format to YUV 4:2:0:

```
ffmpeg -start_number 837 -i '%3d_1.png' -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

In order to control the quality, use the `-crf` option. See the [x264 encoding guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for more info.

#### Why the `*` glob does not work

Don't use the `*` as an input option. The shell will expand it to all files in the current directory before `ffmpeg` sees it, so the command would expand to `ffmpeg -i file1 file2 … filen`. Since all input files in `ffmpeg` need the `-i` option, it'll take `file2 … filen` as output files instead and overwrite them. Not good.

Comment: very complete answer! and do you also have some advice on animated gif?

Comment: For animated GIFs, you want to update to ffmpeg version 2.0 and above, because they greatly improved the visual quality. The [download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page has some links to static builds for OS X. For older ffmpeg, see: [ffmpeg converts .flv video to .gif with awful quality](http://superuser.com/questions/556029/ffmpeg-converts-flv-video-to-gif-with-awful-quality/556031#556031)

Comment: In fact, it not only checks +0..4 but also 8,16,32,64 etc. This is noticeable when using HTTP url's. However, `image2` fails to recognize that `200 OK` is the equivalent of "file found" so it doesn't stop searching.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing even after trying to implement your suggestions. My files are named `DSCxxxxx.jpg` where `xxxxx` is a 5-digit number starting with zero (note I have no underscores). Still, after running `ffmpeg -r 30 -start_number 04606 -i DSC%d.jpg out.mp4` I get the same error as in the original post above

Comment: @jphollowed Did you put the file name pattern in quotes?

Comment: What got me was that the `-start_number` parameter has to be _before_ the `-i` parameter. Also use `-vframes` for a stop number.

Comment: You rock.  This also worked for me on Windows 10.  The color output detail was what I needed.

Answer (score 36):

Globbing can be enabled by specifying **`-pattern_type glob`** option:

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i '*.png' -vcodec libx264 out.mp4
```

Comment: Much better way :)

Comment: Only this worked for me. No way to get this `xxx%d.png`, `xxx%3d.png`, `'xxx%d.png'` or `'xxx%3d.png'` thing working

Comment: I get the same error after trying this: `[image2 @ 0x2552560] Could find no file with path '*.jpg' and index in the range 0-4
*.jpg: No such file or directory`

Comment: Pattern type 'glob' was selected but globbing is not supported by this libavformat build   [using Windows ffmpeg] [oof, should have scrolled down one answer]

Answer (score 10):

Note: Pattern globbing does not work under Windows (and may never due to lack of support for globbing in libavfilter under Windows.) So, if your doing this under Windows, you'll have to rename the files so that they're numbered sequentially and without gaps.

You can rename them with a simple Powershell command line:

```
dir *.jpg | %{$x=0} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName “Base$x”; $x++ }
```

Comment: This will return `file1.jpg` `file2.jpg`…`file10.jpg` which if you sort alphabetically would end up `file1.jpg`, `file10.jpg`…`file2.jpg`

Comment: Shouldn't that be Base$x.jpg? As-is, yours renamed all mine and killed the file extensions.

Answer (score 10):

better way to rename with PowerShell (preserve order) :

```
dir *.jpg | %{$x=0} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName "Base$($x.tostring('000000')).jpg"; $x++ }
```

Comment: Does `dir` always return the files sorted alphabetically? Would it be safer to add a `sort-object` into the mix?