# Turn MP4 into an animated GIF

Tags: mp4, gif

Not sure if this a specific photoshop related issue or if there's another workaround but I have a 5 second MP4 file which has 5 or 6 multiple photos stitched together, is there a way of turning it into an animated GIF file so I can use it on social media websites like FaceBook and Twitter?

Comment: Using ffmpeg: http://superuser.com/questions/556029/how-do-i-convert-a-video-to-gif-using-ffmpeg-with-reasonable-quality

Comment: For which operating system? This should be rather asked at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See: [Free GIF animator](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3237/3474), [A portable, free and simple video editor](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/17996/3474)

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to get each frame and then use them as frames in your GIF.

Gram Smith gave some webapp options to do it and the [WebApps sister-site has many more](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/web-app-to-convert-images-to-web-friendly-formats-of-gif-or-png), or you can [use a program like ffmpeg as described here](https://superuser.com/questions/556029/how-do-i-convert-a-video-to-gif-using-ffmpeg-with-reasonable-quality).

If using Photoshop, you could step through each video frame in a video player like MPC-HC (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>) and save each frame as an image file (or [use the Windows Clipboard](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/take-screen-capture-print-screen#take-screen-capture-print-screen=windows-8)). If not using the clipboard a lossless format like PNG is better for this. Then take your image files and load them into Photoshop as described in [Photoshop Help / Creating frame animations](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-frame-animations.html). Or if using the clipboard paste them in as layers, and use layer visibility to control the active frame in the GIF process.