# Concatenate a list of files with different resolutions

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, mp4, gif

I have a list of mp4 files which are of kb's or of at max 4 MB (they were actually gifs but downloaded as mp4).So when I concatenate them using a list of them the video don't work as all of them are of different sizes (resolution wise ) and all of not are in vertical order.So any help with that matter and also I f someone would be kind enough to tell me the FFmpeg command to convert this mp4 list to gif 's without losing quality.Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll have to re-encode once, while specifying a fixed resolution and frame rate. Then you generate a palette, and then the GIF.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [fps](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps), [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale), [setsar](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setdar_002c-setsar), [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts), [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat), [palettegen](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#palettegen), and [paletteuse](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#paletteuse) filters.

#### 1. Make all inputs uniform, concatenate, then generate the palette

```
    ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -i input2 -filter_complex \
    "[0:v]fps=10,scale=320:240,setsar=1/1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
     [1:v]fps=10,scale=320:240,setsar=1/1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
     [2:v]fps=10,scale=320:240,setsar=1/1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; \
     [v0][v1][v2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0,palettegen[out]" \
    -map "[out]" palette.png
```

- You may not need fps but you did not show any info about your inputs so I had to make assumptions.

#### 2. Encode to GIF

```
    ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -i input2 -i palette.png -filter_complex \
    "[0:v]fps=10,scale=320:240,setsar=1/1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
     [1:v]fps=10,scale=320:240,setsar=1/1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
     [2:v]fps=10,scale=320:240,setsar=1/1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; \
     [v0][v1][v2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[vv]; \
     [vv][3:v]paletteuse[out]" \
    -map "[out]" output.gif
```

- You can't "convert MP4 to GIF without losing quality", but there is a small chance you may not notice much of a difference since you said the MP4 were created from GIF. It all depends on what your inputs look like and how many colors there are.

#### Also see

- [How do I convert a video to GIF using ffmpeg, with reasonable quality?](https://superuser.com/a/556031/110524)

Comment: thanks for great and brief answer but as of input 1,2,3 and so on it would be a very hard job as I have over 100 files.Is there any way I can use mylist.txt file containing all files information like in this example            `FFmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4`

Comment: In short i would like to do all of this for files in a bulk if that would be possible

Comment: Use `ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -vf  "fps=10,scale=320:240,setsar=1,palettegen[out]" 
    -map "[out]" palette.png` for first command. And `ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -i palette.png -filter_complex "[0:v]fps=10,scale=320:240,setsar=1[v0];[v0][1:v],palettegen[out]" 
    -map "[out]" -fflags +genpts output.gif`

Comment: @mulvya error for your 1st command `Output with label 'out' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere.`

Comment: Sorry, it's a vf so remove `[out]` and `-map "[out]"`

Comment: Update:     @Mulvya added `-filter_complex` but now its saying it can't find a suitable format for output

Comment: to me it seems even if it worked it would generate a single file named pallete.png...What I would do with that @Mulvya

Comment: As guessed output is a single palette file of 2kb and this `[Parsed_palettegen_3 @ 05e73ba0] 255(+1) colors generated out of 319259 colors;
ratio=0.000799
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.03 bitrate=N/A speed=0.000728x
video:1kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
`

Comment: Use `ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -i palette.png -filter_complex "[0:v]fps=10,scale=320:240,setsar=1[v0];[v0][1:v]paletteuse[out]" -map "[out]" -fflags +genpts output.gif`

Comment: @Mulvya I really appreciate all of your help but none of this is seem to be working but thanks anyway...Last command just is going on and on and not producing any result

Comment: Which command? 1st or 2nd?

Comment: @Mulvya the last one `Use ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -i palette.png -filter_complex "[0:v]fps=10,scale=320:240,setsar=1[v0];[v0][1:v]paletteuse[out]" -map "[out]" -fflags +genpts output.gif`

Comment: If you have 100+ videos, it will take time. Is the ffmpeg console output showing the fps counter increasing?