# How do I make a gif with text over frames

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm currently converting a video to a gif with the following command (taken from [this example](https://superuser.com/a/556031/535078))

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 30 -t 3 -i input.flv \
-vf fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen palette.png

ffmpeg -ss 30 -t 3 -i input.flv -i palette.png -filter_complex \
"fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" output.gif
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is have text show on the top of the gif while it plays but I'm slightly confused as to how I add in the command below tweaked from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17624103/4180276)

```
drawtext="fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf: \
text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=black: x=160: y=-1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would insert it after the scaling but before the palette filters.

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 30 -t 3 -i input.flv \
-vf fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,drawtext="fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf: \
 text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=black: x=160: y=-1",palettegen palette.png

ffmpeg -ss 30 -t 3 -i input.flv -i palette.png -filter_complex \
"fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,drawtext="fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf: \
 text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=black: x=160: y=-1"[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" output.gif
```

Comment: Do I have to add it to both loops or just one?

Comment: Strictly speaking, just the 2nd, but the quality will be worse, since the palette won't have accounted for the text.

Comment: I'm having a issue when I run the second pass where it doesn't detect the font file, but the first pass does?

Comment: added a edit to fix the command

Comment: @nadermx  The command as written works here on Win 7. I think the use of quotes is shell-specific.