# ffmpeg create gif for multiple videos in a folder

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-encoding

I have hundreds of videos in a folder `/home/videos/` and I would like to create a gif for each video.

The gif should be comprised of 10 different screenshots across the videos length. So for example if a video is 30 minutes long a screenshot should be taken every 3 minutes and all the 10 screenshots should be turned into a gif.

The gif must also be called exactly what the video is named. For example `'/home/videos/video 1 (test).mp4` gif should be saved to `'/home/videos/video 1 (test).gif'`

Can I do this with ffmpeg?

Comment: Your question is very broad, but you could accomplish this with a combination of batch/bash/PowerShell, [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/556031/911683) and [this documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video).

Comment: That appears to just make a gif for 3 seconds 30 seconds into the video. I want a gif made up of 10 images (2 seconds long each) spread evenly across the length of the video.