# FFMPEG scale video according to image height when overlaying video on image

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images

I am trying to overlay a video over an image in FFMPEG. For this I am using the below command.

```
-i C:\Users\Vivek\Desktop\SAM\Effects\bubbles.mp4 -i C:\Users\Vivek\Desktop\selfie.jpg -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[ua][b];[ua]setsar=1,format=yuva444p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[u];[b][u]overlay[v]" -map "[v]" C:\Users\Vivek\Desktop\selfie.gif
```

The above commands work perfectly but this stretches the image according to the video's width while I want the reverse of it i.e to stretch video to width and height of image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the inputs to the scale2ref filter.

```
[0:v][1:v]scale2ref[ua][b]
```

Comment: Is it different from switching the input files? I tried switching the input files but that didn't worked

Comment: What happened ?

Comment: Since I am using this wirh unity so my ide just hanged when I did that

Comment: Run it from a shell and check. Should eliminate IDE from the equation.

Comment: Okay I will check and revert back.