# Add image above gif with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

I cut out the top part of a 320x356 gif as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i image.gif -filter:v "crop=320:226:0:130" out.gif
```

I have a text image that I want to put where the cut out part was; how do I do this? Preferably with as little quality loss as possible (but also preferably without an explosion in file size). Also if there's quality loss from the crop, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the [vstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vstack) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.gif -i input.png -filter_complex "[0]crop=320:226:0:130[bottom];[1][bottom]vstack" out.gif
```

`input.png` needs to be the same width as the cropped GIF. If it is not then add the scale, pad, and/or crop filters.

If you want better quality then adapt [How do I convert a video to GIF using ffmpeg, with reasonable quality?](https://superuser.com/questions/556029/how-do-i-convert-a-video-to-gif-using-ffmpeg-with-reasonable-quality/556031#556031)

```
ffmpeg -i input.gif -i input.png -filter_complex "[0]crop=320:226:0:130[bottom];[1][bottom]vstack,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" out.gif
```

Comment: Change that to `vstack` and I'll accept!

Comment: @Blrp Fixed the typo.