# Create GIF of a transparent image sliding up a normal image

Tags: ffmpeg

I've always used `ffmpeg` to create simple GIFs, never worked with superimposing a transparent PNG on an image. How do I do that?

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve this? This site doesn’t provide step-by-step tutorials for those who cannot even show the minimal effort. This site helps those who have at least started to do something and is stuck.

Comment: Also see [How do I convert a video to GIF using ffmpeg, with reasonable quality?](https://superuser.com/q/556029/)

Comment: @llogan, thank you, but that question doesn't concern with overlays.

Comment: @klaus No, it does not, but you were asking about creating GIFs. The default GIF output from ffmpeg is poor. I assumed you didn't want a poor quality output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `overlay` filter to superimpose. It takes care of the transparency in the foreground image automatically. Example:

[image: Animated GIF with transparent foreground]

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i background.jpg -i foreground-with-transparent-regions.png -filter_complex "overlay=x=0:y=H-(H+h)*t/3" -t 3 output.gif
```

`-loop 1` makes it repeat the image so that we have a duration despite using single image.

The `overlay` filter (added with `filter_complex` syntax here) places the foreground image at the (x, y) position, where `x` is constant here (0), and `y` is a calculated over time with an expression involving the background and foreground heights, as well as the current time in seconds denoted by `t` in the expression, to produce the slide-up animation as shown above.

`-t` defines the duration of the output

Comment: Thanks! I only had to add an if-else condition to your solution to get what I needed. Something like keeping the cookies stuck in the middle instead of keep sliding up. `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i background.png -i cookies.png -filter_complex "overlay=x=0:y='if(lt(H-(H+h)*t/3\,0)\,0\,H-(H+h)*t/3)'" -t 3 output.gif`