# ffmpeg - Add text to existing gif without gif decolorization / pixilation

Tags: ffmpeg, images, gif

I am trying to add text to a gif, but after I add it there is some image decolorization & pixilation that happens.

The command I am running on a to add text to the gif is as follows:

`ffmpeg -i test.gif -vf "drawtext=fontfile=OpenSans.ttf:text='Stack Overflow':fontcolor=black:fontsize=24" copy output.gif`

If anyone had any insight on why the distortion / decolorization might be happening. It would be appreciated!

Here is an example gif, then the result of running the command above.

**Original Gif**:

[image]

**After: (post ffmpeg)**:

[image]

(don't worry he goes back to get the cat)

Comment: fyi, this distortion of color is typically called "dithering" see also: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/32656/how-to-turn-off-ffmpeg-dithering

Comment: glad to know he went back for the cat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapt the command as shown in [How do I convert a video to GIF using ffmpeg, with reasonable quality](https://superuser.com/a/556031/):

```
ffmpeg -i input.gif -vf "drawtext=fontfile=OpenSans.ttf:text='Stack Overflow':fontcolor=black:fontsize=24,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" output.gif
```

Answer (score 1):

So I stumbled my way into a working solution, I'm not sure if it's optimal but it works.

I convert to a .mp4 then add the text, then convert back down to a .gif

**Convert to mp4** (you will need to set your own font here)

```
ffmpeg -i test.gif -vf "drawtext=fontfile=OpenSans.ttf:text='Stack Overflow':fontcolor=black:fontsize=24" -codec:a copy output.mp4
```

**Convert back to gif**

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -filter_complex 'fps=10,scale=500:-1:flags=lanczos,split [o1] [o2];[o1] palettegen [p]; [o2] fifo [o3];[o3] [p] paletteuse' final.gif
```

This results in the image rendering properly with the text (bottom right):

[image]

I'm not sure if this is optimal, or what these complex flags are really doing. I'm also arbitrarily setting the scale to 500 because if I don't the final gif is tiny.

So if anyone has a better solution, please do post here!

Comment: No need to convert to MP4 first. Just adapt the command as shown in [How do I convert a video to GIF using ffmpeg, with reasonable quality](https://superuser.com/a/556031/), so `ffmpeg -i input.gif -vf "drawtext=fontfile=OpenSans.ttf:text='Stack Overflow':fontcolor=black:fontsize=24,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" output.gif`

Comment: thank you @llogan ! This makes sense, feel free to post as an answer so I can accept