# Add single pixel to .gif file using ffmpeg

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, gif, animation, animated-gif

I have several thousand .gif files (with alpha channels) and I want to add a single red pixel (no transparency) in the bottom left hand corner of each .gif file. Each one has different dimensions.

How can I do this easily with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1):

Adapting [How do I convert a video to GIF using ffmpeg, with reasonable quality?](https://superuser.com/a/556031/) by adding the [drawbox](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawbox) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.gif -vf "drawbox=x=0:y=ih-h:w=1:h=1:color=red:t=fill:replace=1,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" output.gif
```

If the pixel does not show up increase the `h` value or you may have to adjust the options for [palettegen](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#palettegen)/[paletteuse](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#paletteuse).

Comment: Thanks. I had to make h 2 for it to show up, but it looks like that made it 2 pixels in height. Although this is good enough for my purposes, I guess I'm curious why it doesn't work when h = 1.

Comment: @jippyjoe4 I don't know. Probably something to do with palettegen. Check the source code.