# Overlay GIF on MP4 at certain time interval (while maintaining GIF transparency) [FFMPEG]

Tags: ffmpeg, video, image-processing

I'm looking for a way to implement a gif overlay on top of an mp4, having the following characteristics:

- Maintaining GIF transparency on video
- Having the GIF only showing up for a certain time interval (etc. 0:02-0:06)
- Positioning the GIF on the bottom left corner of the MP4 file

Comment: I corrected a mistake. It should be `y=H-h` not W-w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `x=between(t, 2, 6), 0, NAN)` [Expression Evaluation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#toc-Expression-Evaluation) and `y=(H-h)`.
See `overlay` filter [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-overlay-1) (read the examples - they are close enough).

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.mp4 -i in.gif -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=x='if(between(t, 2, 6), 0, NAN):y=(H-h)':format=yuv444" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv444p -crf 17 -acodec copy out.mp4
```

`format=yuv444` and `-pix_fmt yuv444p` are used for improving the output quality.

I used the transparent gif from my following [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1703971/drawing-text-on-a-gif-while-preserving-transparency-ffmpeg), and overlay with synthetic pattern.

Output frame sample:
[image]

---

Building the synthetic pattern (used for testing):

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -r 10 -i testsrc=size=640x480:rate=1:duration=300 -vf setpts=N/10/TB -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv444p -crf 17 in.mp4
```

GIF image with transparency:
[image]