# How to preserve the input transparently after performing gif above png

Tags: ffmpeg

i have the following command to overlay gif above png

```
String command = '-y -i $path.png -i $path.gif -filter_complex '
             '[1:v]scale=200:200[i1];'
             '[0:v][i1]overlay=100:100'
             ' -q:v 1 $output.gif';
```

it work fine , but the problem is that my first input `($path.png)` is no longer transparently as what it was before execute .

in other word : before i execute the command my `path.png` has rounded corners and transparently background , when i overlay the `gif` above it so it totally effect `path.png` like it remove the rounded corners and background became black .

when i overlay `png` instead of `gif` so it does not effect the `path.png` and everything is fine .

So how to to overlay gif with preserving the transparently of `path.png` and it's rounded corner too . thanks

**Edit**

this is the first input `(png)`

[image]

this is second input `(gif)`

[image]

Now i am trying to overlay the second input `(gif)` above the first input `(png)`

```
'-y -i png -i gif -filter_complex '
             '[1:v]scale=$w:$h[i1];'
             '[0:v][i1]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)-10'
             ' -q:v 1 outputGif';
```

OUTPUT

[image]

as you can see , it lost the black transparently and rounded corners

and the following is @Rotem command

```
 '-y -i png  -i gif -filter_complex '
             '"[1:v]scale=$w:$h[i1];'
             '[0:v][i1]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)-10:'
             'format=auto,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen=reserve_transparent=1[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" -q:v 1 outputGif';
```

**output**

[image]

it became totally transparent . but i am trying to keep that black transparent background like original and not fully transparent

Answer (score 0):

For keeping transparently for both GIF and PNG, we may use the following syntax:

`ffmpeg -y -i in.png -i in.gif -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=200:200[i1];[0:v][i1]overlay=100:100:format=auto,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen=reserve_transparent=1[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" -q:v 1 out.gif`

---

- `overlay=100:100:format=auto,format=rgba` - forces the overlay output pixel format to be `rgba` (keeping transparency).
  Note: It's working with FFmpeg 5.1.2 (I didn't test older versions).
- `[s0]palettegen=reserve_transparent=1[p];[s1][p]paletteuse` - generates a new palette for the output GIF as in the [following answer](https://superuser.com/a/556031/635712).
  The new palette matches the colors of the new overlaid image.
  `reserve_transparent=1` generates the palette with transparency.

---

Testing:

`out.gif`:
[image]

`in.png`:
[image]

`in.gif`:
[image]

Comment: deeply thanks @Rotem , this is work perfectly but i think I'm expressing it wrong with (transparently word) , i mean it has black background say 0.5 degree  (not totally transparently )  , after testing your command it totally make the background transparently where i want to preserve the original one which has black transparently  background  (but totally transparent)

Comment: command = '-y -i $png -i $gif -filter_complex ' '"[1:v]scale=$w:$h[i1];' '[0:v][i1]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)-$fromBottom:' 'format=auto,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen=reserve_transparent=1[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" -q:v 1 $gif';

Comment: Can you please edit your question, and add sample input images? (you don't have to post the real images, just images that reproduce the issue). Please use file names instead of `$png`, `$gif`... and replace `command =` with full FFmpeg command. Can you please make sure that animated GIF format supports semi-transparent background? I think it is not supported. See [this post](https://ezgif.com/help/gif-transparency) for example.

Comment: thanks for taking one more try help , i am scary if i did not understand you but i did my best in EDIT , please take a look

Comment: When I edit the PNG image into [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfrjv.png), my solution seems to work. The issue is that most of the area of your PNG input image is semi-transparent (the gray part is 60% transparent and 40% opaque). Animated GIF format doesn't support semi-transparent pixels, only 100% transparent and 100% opaque. We may use FFmpeg to pass some threshold over the PNG transparency, making most area 100% opaque and make the corners 100% transparent but I think it's out of the scope of the question...

Comment: thanks for telling me these info, i wasn't know that, so in final do you think there are no way to do my desired using ffmpeg ?

Comment: In case what you want is similar to the following Animated PNG: `ffmpeg -y -i in.png -i in.gif -filter_complex "[0:v]format=rgba[v0];[1:v]scale=200:50[i1];[v0][i1]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)-10:format=auto" -plays 0 out.apng`, It is not possible using Animated GIF. The gray background of the Animated GIF can't be semi-transparent.

Comment: thanks you , so i understand from you that i must choice another gif that support semi-transparent in order to do my desired output in my question ?  in other word i mean does it possible to find gif that supporting semi-transparent ? if yes so which command of yours is for this ? your last command it working perfectly as expected but my gif in no longer animated anymore :( ..  deeply thanks

Comment: Animated GIF format supports only two type of transparency: "transparent" and "not transparent". There is no support for "half transparent" pixels. The above example uses **Animated PNG** instead of Animated GIF. Animated PNG supports "half transparent" pixels. Animated PNG is support is less common, so you probably can't use Animated PNG format.

Comment: thank you , after reading your comment carefully, i tested above command with Animated PNG instead gif  https://lukeroberts.tv/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/apng1.png , there are no animated in output but it preserve the half-transparent 

'-y -i $png -i https://lukeroberts.tv/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/apng1.png'
             ' -filter_complex "[0:v]format=rgba[v0];[1:v]scale=200:50[i1];[v0][i1]'
             'overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)-10:format=auto" -plays 0 $.apng';